Using indirect to call different excel functions
Is it possible to use indirect to dynamically call different excel functions?
For example, cells A2:A10 contain my raw data, named "data",
Cell B2 contains the text "stdev".
Cell B3 contains the text "average".
In cell C2, I want to calculate stdev(data),
In cell C3, I want to calculate average(data).
By changing C2 from "stdev" to "max" C2 should now calculate max(data)
My formula: "= indirect (b2)(data)" does not work.  Excel replaces the formula with = indirect (b2)*(data) which is not what I want and also results in a #SPILL! error.

"Is it possible to use indirect to dynamically call different excel functions?" No, it is not. Check MS Help for the proper argument to the INDIRECT function.

Have a look at AGGREGATE. It will not do SKEW or KURT but it has a lot of the less exotic range aggregation functions.

INDIRECT doesn't seem to fit for you.
If the functions you need to use are specific, and do not change often, then maybe you could try using nested IFs.
In your case, if you only need AVERAGE, STDEV and MAX, then this should work for you:
=IF(B2="average";AVERAGE(data);IF(B2="max";MAX(data);STDEV(data))
Type this function in cell C2.
Also type the following in cell C3:
=IF(B3="average";AVERAGE(data);IF(B3="max";MAX(data);STDEV(data))

While this indeed is a solution, nested IFs should be avoided.  It's much better to use either IFS (if using O2019/2019) or SWITCH.

Michal, I appreciate your suggestions.  However, I was hoping INDIRECT would work with simple functions.  By simple function, I mean functions that only need a range and not other inputs.  I'm trying to avoid hardcoding with IF statements, because I'm already thinking of using other functions such as SKEW and KURT.

Would you be able to use SUBTOTAL function - Microsoft Support like this?
=SUBTOTAL(SWITCH(B3,"max",4,"min",5,1),data)

Assume you have set the named range "data" = F1:F7
You have the the string max (no quotation) in H1
You can then create a cell with =CONCAT(H1,"(data)") I have this in J1
Using name-manager you can create the function =EVALUATE(Sheet1!$J$1) I named this function to "dunfunc"
Writing =dynfunc in any cell will give you your dynamic evaluation.

Good point @W_O_L_F. As EVALUATE is a Macro function, use of it requires file to be saved as macro-enabled.
